# Database column is of double data type instead of integer

Tags: c#, ms-access

The database I'm writing into has a double data type instead of integer (DRAMT and CRAMT columns) even though I have I initialized the table columns to integer. I suspect it's because of my operation below. Really have no idea how to approach this though so that the said columns would display as integers with no floating points at all.

```
int dramt = 0;
int cramt = 0;
double ddramt = 0;
double ccramt = 0;

if (type == "50")
    ddramt = 100 *dt.Rows[n].Field<double>(2);
else if(type == "51")
    ccramt = 100 *dt.Rows[n].Field<double>(2);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRAMT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = dramt;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CRAMT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = cramt;
```

The code used to create the table is show below:

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + FileName + " ([JNL] VarChar(4), " +
                                                   "[LINE] VarChar(5), "+
                                                   "[TYPE] VarChar(6), "+
                                                   "[DRACC] VarChar(9), "+
                                                   "[CRACC] VarChar(9), "+
                                                   "[EXPDRACC] VarChar(11), "+
                                                   "[EXPCRACC] VarChar(11), "+
                                                   "[DRSTITLE] VarChar(9), "+
                                                   "[CRSTITLE] VarChar(9), "+
                                                   "[DOCDATE] DateTime, "+
                                                   "[REF] VarChar(8), "+
                                                   "[DRAMT] Integer, "+
                                                   "[CRAMT] Integer, "+
                                                   "[LARGE] VarChar(7), "+
                                                   "[DESC] VarChar(6), "+
                                                   "[TRACE] VarChar(6), "+
                                                   "[TRNDR] VarChar(7), "+
                                                   "[TRNCR] VarChar(7), "+
                                                   "[PARTS1] VarChar(8), "+
                                                   "[PARTS2] VarChar(8), "+
                                                   "[PARTS3] VarChar(8), "+
                                                   "[PARTS4] VarChar(8), "+
                                                   "[PARTS5] VarChar(8))";
```

Comment: The type of the column is based on the code used to create the table, not on the values inserted into the column.

Comment: As said, I did create the table with the columns set to integer.

Comment: If you look at the data in Access itself does the data have decimal places?

Comment: You can try being explicit about your integer size: `"[DRAMT] Integer4, "+
                                                                 "[CRAMT] Integer4, "+`

Comment: Check in the Access table, in the specific field, what is the value of the [`DecimalPlaces`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-Property-Number-and-Currency-Data-Types-CA77795E-B40D-4ABB-B42F-DAA0BB709620) property. in Access an integer can have a decimal value